# Index was out of range error when I add a UserControl to a panel, Microsoft VS C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, extension-methods

The behavior of code change between projects

For the first project it runs good 
I have a string array `s[] = ...` and `s.Count();` this function exist 
 and when I add a control to my panel it goes fine.

On the other project

1) `s.C`  and click on (ctrl-space) it shows me only `CopyTo` and `Clone` methods

> this part is solved as Tim, Ganesh, and Patrick said, by adding `using System.Linq;`

2) When I try to add a control to a panel with
   `panel.Controls.Add( Custom Control );`
   it shows me an error in a messagebox and it add the 
   control and program continues without a problem

> index was out of range. Must be non negative and 
>      less than the size of collection 
>  Parameter name: index

The add code is not in a `try-catch`
I tried to change frameworks it didn't change anything 
what could be the problem, thanks reading about my problem, and for any help.

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Also make sure that you are targeting .NET 3.5 or above

Comment: ok thank you very much Tim and Ganesh for you fast replay, i will use system.linq and i am using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Count()` is an extension method and those are only available when the namespace they are defined in is referenced. That is because extension methods are not defined on the class you are calling, but somewhere external. (Hence the name 'extension' method)

You need to include this on top of your code file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Although it is better to call `s.Length` since your variable is just an array.

Comment: thank you very much Patrick for you fast replay and for your explanation, i will try what you said